# I can't connect all wolfram websites if I use VPN

Tags: internet

I can connect wolfram's sites if I connect them directly,but once I connect my vpn,even mathematica can't connect to the internet.And there is no problem to connect other sites.Why does this happen?Thx!

Comment: Details about your set-up please

Comment: Protocol is pptp,vpn ip is 198.71.92.71 , OS is Windows8.1,this is my friend's vpn.He just gave a account to me,so I don't know more info...